# Google Script as a webhook receiver

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, webhooks

I'm trying to establish Google Drive webhooks using `POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch`.

And I'd like to use my Google Script app (web app) as the webhook receiver.
(**url**: [https://script.google.com/a/swit.io/macros/s/{script_id}/exec](https://script.google.com/a/swit.io/macros/s/%7Bscript_id%7D/exec))

But when I tried this, the Drive API returned the error `Unauthorized WebHook callback channel`.

Because `script.google.com` isn't my own domain, it's not possible to verify it on my GCP account.

How can I pair **Google Script** and **Google Drive webhook service**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drive API Push Notifications for a Google Apps Script Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631850/drive-api-push-notifications-for-a-google-apps-script-web-app)

Comment: Totally. Thanks.